# regular covering proof

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Here is my problem:

Let $S_g$ be an orientable closed curved surface (like sphere or torus) with genus $g$. With arbitrary $g\geq3$ show that $S_g$ is a regular covering of $S_2$.

I have no idea how to approach this problem since I struggle a lot in writing proofs concerning covering spaces. Any pieces of advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is the first time for me using this site. If there is something unclear in the formatting or the question please let me know so I can make better questions in the future.

Comment: I think you might have been downvoted for "lack of effort". I know that when you don't know how to approach a problem it's hard to write something down but I'm positive that something can always be said about your effort/approach. Said this, I haven't down voted you so in reality I don't know the actual reason of the real down-voter

Comment: Luigi M: I was not looking for complete answers, only for something to get started. Thank you for your advice. I try to be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us deal with standard covering first, then we will see the normal/regular one. A standard trick when dealing with this kind of problems is to use multiplicativity of the Euler characteristic $\chi$. In particular, for a $k$-sheeted cover $E$ of a compact CW-complex $X$ the following formula holds: $$\chi(E)=k\cdot \chi(X)$$ This simple formula (which is not hard to prove, I believe you can find a proof on any standard algebraic topology book) gives you a good starting point when dealing with finding covering spaces of a manifold.

In this case we plug-in $E=S_g$ and $X=S_2$, with the formula $\chi(S_g)=2-2g$ to obtain that the degree of the covering must be $k=g-1$. (you should do these computation to see why we assumed $g\geq 3$, actually $g=2$ is not a big problem :) ).

Now the covering maps are given in the following way. Draw your oriented surface $S_g$ with one of the hole in the centred and the other (which are $g-1$!) evenly spaced around it. The free action is given by rotating around the central hole. Note that it does define a (free) group action of $\Bbb Z/(g-1)\Bbb Z$ on $S_g$ and you should prove that the quotient is really $S_2$ (basically notice that you are identify all the "rays" emanating from the central hole - this gives you intuition on why you get $S_2"- then formally prove that the quotient has all the properties required).

A similar setting is depicted by Hatcher (page 73)

[image]

Where the difference is that the quotient is $S_3$ and therefore on each ray we have $2$ holes. You should work out the details of this.

For what concern regularity of the cover let me be a little bit sketchy:every covering action arising as nice group action like this (I'll refer to prop 1.40 page 72 of Hatcher for the precise statement) gives rise to a regular (normal in Hatcher notation) cover.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I found out the sources (Allen Hatcher) very helpful. I should be able to continue from here.

Comment: if you think this answer answer your question you should mark it as accepted (green check on left-top of my answer)